# how to select pdf file using intent and get that selected pdf file path in onActivityResult

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, mime-types

- I am trying to select pdf using intent and get that selected pdf file path I am not sure its right or wrong.
- if not then how can I get pdf path in `onActivityResult`.

.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("pdf/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF"), PDF_PICKER_RESULTS);
```

Comment: [link](https://plugpdf.com/a-simple-pdf-picker/) is this right way ??

Comment: Firstly, change the type to `"applicaiton/pdf"`

Answer (score 1):

> using application/pdf line i can do this things.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF"), PDF_PICKER_RESULTS);
```